# Need help for relative paths imports

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, path, python-import

Please find attached my files structure:

[image]

- My `micro_service.py` file requires the `app_config.ini` on startup. Here is how I call the .ini file from it.

```
app_config = ConfigParser()
app_config.read("./app_config.ini")
CONFIG_SECTION_APP = app_config.sections()[0]
```

- My `test_micro_service.py` needs to import all the functions in the `micro_service.py` file to test them since it's a unit tests file.

This is how I used to import my functions until now that I added the `.ini` file procedure:

```
root = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
sys.path.append(root)
from micro_service import micro_service
```

The issue I'm facing is that due to changing the working directory using the `sys.path` command, inside the `test_micro_service.py` file, when importing my `.ini` file, the working directory being different causes `"./app_config.ini"` not to be found (which makes sense) and so it causes my tests to fail because `CONFIG_SECTION_APP = []`

I did read plenty of stuff on the internet but I would like to know what are the simplest/cleanest ways do it ?

Console output:

```
================================================================================================================== ERRORS ==================================================================================================================
____________________________________________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting unit_tests/test_micro_service.py _____________________________________________________________________________________________
unit_tests\test_micro_service.py:4: in <module>
    from micro_service import micro_service
micro_service\micro_service.py:16: in <module>
    CONFIG_SECTION_APP = app_config.sections()[0]
E   IndexError: list index out of range
```

Content of the ini file:

```
; Configuration file used by micro_service.py

[APP]
DICT_VERSION_GENERAL  = 1.0
DICT_VERSION_PERSONAL = 1.0
```

**I found the solution to my problem:**

This is how I should call my file inside the `micro_service.py`

```
app_config.read(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + "\\app_config.ini")
```

Comment: Could you show show the content of the .ini file ?

Comment: Yes but that s not the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pathlib.Path` :

```
# in micro_service.py
from pathlib import Path

app_config = ConfigParser()
path = Path().resolve() / "app_config.ini"
app_config.read(path)
CONFIG_SECTION_APP = app_config.sections()[0]
```

Comment: It doesn't fix the problem for me, I still have the same exact error

Comment: Ok, sorry. I'm gonna search another solution